# Multiple clipboards: How can I copy to clipboard 1 with Ctrl+Shift+1 and paste with Ctrl+1, etc?

Tags: keyboard, mac, copy-paste

I want to be able to do the following:

1. Select text (e.g., `example text one`)
2. Hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`1`
3. Select text 2 (e.g., `example text two`)
4. Hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`2`
5. Hit `Ctrl`+`1` and paste `example text one`
6. Hit `Ctrl`+`2` and paste `example text two`

I've been through a number of clipboard managers trying to find this functionality:

1. [Maccy](https://github.com/p0deje/Maccy/tree/master)
2. [Paste](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/paste-clipboard-manager/id967805235)
3. [CopyClip](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/copyclip-clipboard-history/id595191960?mt=12)
4. [FlyCut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut)
5. [CopyPro](https://copypro.app/)
6. [Raycast](https://www.raycast.com/)
7. [LaunchBar](https://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar)
8. [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/)

Some of the options above will let me paste with `Cmd`+`1` (etc.), but **none of them will let me copy into slot #1 with a numerical hotkey.**

I already have a use for `Cmd`+, so I would really like `Ctrl`-based hotkeys.

Back in the day on Windows, I used AutoHotkey to write code to do this.  It was pretty easy.

Other points:

1. I only need slots 0-9 available.
2. I'm only looking for plaintext copy/paste.
3. I don't need a UI.
4. I don't want to have to pay a subscription fee, although a one-time payment would be acceptable.
5. If you suggest a general purpose tool like [Keyboard Maestro](https://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or [Alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com/), please specify how to create the specific functionality I am asking for.

Comment: Does it have to be those specific key shortcuts? That seems to be the limitation. Most of the clipboard apps I've seen use standard Copy, and then Command + number to select which entry you want to use.

Comment: The issue with having the program choose the hotkey is I have to remember the implied index of everything I've copied because every new copy shifts every old copy down by one.  So, I can't really achieve muscle memory with the existing programs.  In addition, I use command+number for activating windows (e.g., Cmd+3 is my IDE, Cmd+4 is my terminal, etc.)  Those are static, so I have muscle memory to bring up my 10 most common programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with Keyboard Maestro.

#### Macro 1

- Hot Key trigger: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`1`
- Action: `Copy to Named Clipboard 4 "clip1"`

#### Macro 2

- Hot Key trigger: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`2`
- Action: `Copy to Named Clipboard 4 "Copy 2"`

#### Macro 3

- Hot Key trigger: `Ctrl`+`1`
- Action: `Paste from Named Clipboard "Copy 1"`

#### Macro 4

- Hot Key trigger: `Ctrl`+`2`
- Action: `Paste from Named Clipboard "Copy 2"`

You can duplicate macros and simply update a few parameters to get all numbers 1-9 working.

I validated this with a trial and then bought the program.